# After I close the listening socket fd, can I continue to accept connections in the backlog finish queue?

Tags: tcp, network-programming

I need to make the server close gracefully recently on Linux. I met some question.

After I close the listen socket fd, 
can I recv and send data with already accepted fd?

can I continue accpet connection in the backlog finish queue?

Comment: Is your question about a specific programming environemnt or language? Please add some background information and improve the grammar of your post. And welcome to SO.

Comment: @simon Why? The answer is the same for all programming environments and languages.

Comment: @EJP: because SO is not just about providing individuals answer to their questions (like Ask Yahoo! for example), but about providing questions and answers in an educating, searchable manner. Also checking the grammar once before posting is not too much to ask IMHO.

Comment: @simon You haven't answered my question. What do the programming environment and language have to do with the question? Answer: nothing. The question is about fundamental properties of the TCP API that are the same on all platforms and in all programming languages. Your question is therefore irrelevant. You are asking for meaningless detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I recv and send data with already accepted fd?

Yes.

> can I continue accpet connection in the backlog finish queue?

No. The listening socket is closed, the backlog queue has been destroyed, the pending connections have been refused, and all further operations on the socket are invalid.